# Error The given document root directory windows

Tags: windows, web-services, symfony, xampp

I'm having issues with running a web project with Symfony on an XAMPP server in Windows. Check the attached link for error description.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUjZv.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application's document root differs from the standard directory layout, you have to pass the correct location using the --docroot option:

> php bin/console server:start --docroot=public_html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html

you are using "run" Try "start"